# MATLAB Engine for Python: Desktop not supported, Swing is not currently available

Tags: matlab, swing, user-interface, desktop, matlab-engine

I need to start MATLAB in Python using `MATLAB Engine API for Python` as www-data with GUI/as desktop app. And the following code results in the error:

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
eng.desktop(nargout=0)
```

When I try to run this code, the `-desktop` argument is just ignored and Matlab runs like `-nodesktop`.

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab('-desktop')
```

Error: `desktop is not supported because: Swing is not currently available.`

How to make it run?

Comment: Do you have swing installed?

Comment: This is what I get when I type `java -version` into the terminal: 
`openjdk version "1.8.0_121"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_121-8u121-b13-0ubuntu1.16.04.2-b13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.121-b13, mixed mode)`, so I guess yes

Comment: Everything works like a charm when I run desired code like the normal user, so the problem is only when trying to run as **www-data**